# Generating text buttons based on mysql records

Tags: php, html, mysql, hyperlink

I have a scenario in where I would like to create button links to allow users to view there own adverts, but the amount of ads will depend from user to user.

For example, John would have 3 ads stored in ads table(username, advertid, adverttitle, advertdescription), and he would have one account in accounts table(username, name, email, password).

When John logs in he would see 3 buttons (not physical buttons but hyperlink buttons), these button names will correspond to adverttitle in mysql database. Once John clicks on any given ad, he can view the advert description, make changes ect (not relevant to my issue though).

I'm not looking for ways to link advert to different forms, I would just like to know how I could create hyperlink buttons (text buttons) which generate depending on how many ads a user has in the advert table (user can have infinite ads, therefore infinite hyperlink buttons, as username is not pk, but advertid is). thanks in advance.

**Note:** I have already created a html form, with PHP connecting to MySQL. I just don't know how to create hyperlinks based on the amount of ads a user has.

advert table example

```
username    advertid    adverttitle advertdes
john345     123         ad1         ad1des  
john345     125         ad2         ad2des  
john345     126         ad3         ad3des
```

user table example

```
username    name        email       password
john345     john        whocares    why
```

Comment: It's really difficult to read this question due to poor formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will first need to query a database and then iterate results over in while loop in order to generate HTML links:

**PDO:**

```
$userId = 'john345';
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM advert WHERE username = :userId';
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$result = $query->execute(array('userId' => $userId));
$output = '';

while ($row = $result->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $output .= '<a href="advert.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</a>';
}

echo $output;
```

Also you can move PDO::FETCH_ASSOC into a connection setup, if you don't want to keep passing this option.

**MySQLi:**

```
$userId = mysqli_real_escape_string('john345');
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM advert WHERE username = '.$userId;
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$output = '';

while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $output .= '<a href="advert.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</a>';
}

echo $output;
```

Comment: that's so good, and it looks like it will do what i want but how would i change it to work with mysqli. thanks in advance.

Comment: Here you are, I've added MySQLi